# Transforming linear dynamical system to reduce magnitude of eigen values

Tags: matrices, dynamical-systems, control-theory, optimal-control, linear-control

Consider a linear dynamical system
$\dot{x} = Ax + Bu$ with eigen values of high magnitude (can be both positive or negative), say in 900's. Can the system be transformed to reduce the magnitude of eigen values, say 900 reduces to 9 and vice versa.

My approach to was to consider a transformation matrix $T$ such that $z = Tx$, where $T$ is transformation matrices. Then the new dynamical system is

$\dot{z} = T\dot{x} = TAx + TBu = TAT^{-1}z + TBu$.

I was however not sure what should be the structure of $T$  be to minimizes the magnitude of eigen values of the system. Any lead in solving the problem will be appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

A [similarity transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_similarity) can only change the eigenvectors and not the eigenvalues. The only way to achieve what you want would be to change the time scale, so $z(\tau)=x(\alpha\,t)$.

Comment: And even that wouldn't help with changing condition number of matrix $A$...

Comment: Thank you for the feedback.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it, although the change of coordinates is generally just continuous (the term topological equivalence may come in handy).

Let me exemplify it for a simple scalar problem. Consider $\dot x=ax$, the solution is $x(t)=\exp(at)x(0)$.

Now let $z=x^{b/a}$. Then the solution is transformed to $z(t)=[\exp(at)x(0)]^{b/a}=(\exp(at))^{b/a}x(0)^{b/a}=\exp(bt)z(0)$, which is the solution of $\dot z = bz$.

Of course a problem is the exponent $b/a$...

As commented previously, if you want a differentiable change of coordinates then the answer is negative, you cannot change the eigenvalues.

Comment: Hi PepeToro, thank you for the response. It surely is a new approach to me but I was wondering that even if the solution is computed then too the result will be very difficult to apply on the actual system. Considering the z will be a trajectory and then taking exponent a/b of it will be difficult to compute x, let alone the higher dimensional matrices. Will the pointwise exponent work for this approach because otherwise the solution will again be difficult to apply.

Comment: @Murt: Both answers are trying to answer your question. Both answer your question (which is not precise enough in terms of what is allowed and what is not allowed). You should at least give an upvote +1 for the answers.

Comment: @Murt: I do net get what you are asking very well. This concept about topological equivalence is mainly used in qualitative studies. It actually tells you that you should not care that much about the value of the eigenvalues, but more about what they imply. Moreover, in order to apply the idea you do not have to compute the operation x^{a/b}, the idea tells you that the system $\dot x=ax$ is "equivalent" to the system $\dot y=by$ as long as $ab>0$ (they have the same sign). That's the whole idea.

Comment: @PepeToro Thank you for the response. Do you have some good reference that I may refer for further consolidating the idea. I am obliged for the response and guidance.

Comment: @MrYouMath Sir I already did but I donot have +15 repo that it may start showing up.